# Is it possible to format (center aligned) a single column of a ListBox?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I want to format a **single** column of a ListBox as *Centered*.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can work around it. If you make a listbox containing 3 columns each with the same column width and you fill column 1 and 3 with nothing or one space and you fill column 2 with data, than it is centered in a way:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With Me.lstBox
        .ColumnCount = 3
        .ColumnWidths = 10
        .BoundColumn = 2
        .AddItem
        .List(0, 1) = "Example"
    End With

End Sub
```

Above code results in:

[image]

I don't think dat VBA has a property to center align data in a listbox (I read that VB6 does have it by the way). But this is not a single column I'll give you that ;)

Comment: Well, that was elegant. Workd

Comment: @FreddyMeijer *"I don't think dat VBA has a property to center allign data in a listbox"* - you might be interested in my answer demonstrating the direct way :-;

Answer (score 1):

A Userform listbox actually *does* dispose of a `TextAlign` property to center align data.

*Side note: generally this would apply the same format to all list columns,
which might not be wanted in other occasions (e.g. for numeric data in additional columns).*

**Possible example assignment**

```
Me.ListBox1.TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
```

Comment: Ha T.M. I learned something new today! Indeed that does do the trick as well. But your side note is indeed correct.